# Which Animal corresponds to which Buddha?

Tags: buddha, animals, amitabha

For example, peacocks are often associated with Amitabha. They were said to be his mounts, and images of Amitabha often feature peacock symbolism.

What about the other Buddhas? Do they each have an associated animal symbol, and what could the animal represent?

Answer (score 2):

In Mahayana and Tibetan Buddhism, various animals are associated with different Buddhas and Bodhisattvas.

[image]

This [web page](https://buddhaweekly.com/kukkuripas-dog-and-the-sacred-animals-in-buddhism-power-animals-of-enlightened-deities-and-their-meaning/) has more information about the sacred animals in Buddhism

Comment: also, the Pali suttas refer to Buddha Shakyamuni as a 'Naga' or 'Cobra'.

Answer (score -1):

No, not all Buddhas have an animal associated with them, in any tradition.